# Chapter-like entries in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am working on a project which is based on a chapter of the Quran. Each so called chapter starts with a quote of a verse from the relevant chapter.

I do not want any chapter headers or chapter numbers, yet I would like to have a chapter like functionality like (1) starting at a new page; (2) have TOC entry.

So for the MWE below, I should have TOC entries but at the same time at those pages where a new chapter starts, no chapter name, number, etc. is displayed. What are my options for such a requirement?

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Verses 1-3}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\chapter{Verse 4}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Verse 1--3}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\clearpage 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Verse 4}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use that kind of functionality a lot, it would be better to wrap it in a command.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=30pc, paperheight=30pc, margin=5pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newcommand{\Verse}[1]{\clearpage\addtocontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}


\begin{document}
\Verse{Verses 1-3}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\Verse{Verse 4}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{document}
```